# Opencart Breadcrumb link inconsistencies

Tags: url, seo, opencart, breadcrumbs

I am having similar problem in my other pages and it’s driving me crazy. I have modified a `“manufacturer”` module to `“series”`
as well as the link too.
For example, I was able to change this link:

```
bishounenboutique.com/manufacturer
```

to this:

```
bishounenboutique.com/series
```

Click on the breadcrumbs, and
the they are fine in that page. However,
if you click on top image “Psycho pass” for example in that link, it will redirect to:

```
bishounenboutique.com/index.php?route=product/manufacturer/product&manufacturer_id=13
```

(which is not what i want. Ideally I want the link to be `bishounenboutique.com/psycho-pass`)

But set that aside, on that page if you click on the breadcrumb link “series”, it gives:

```
bishounenboutique.com/index.php?route=series
```

but it is supposed to be:

```
bishounenboutique.com/series
```

!!!

Can anyone please give me an idea of why this is happening?
I have already enabled SEO url and renamed the htaccess file. But I don't know why it works on some links but not others.
Thank you.

Comment: How did you change your manufacturer url in the first place. It appears you've manually changed the URL

Comment: There is a vqmod that changes index route, here's the code: elseif (isset($data['route']) && $data['route'] ==   'product/manufacturer') { 
            $url .=  '/series';    but any idea why breadcrumbs are inconsistent? It gets rid of the "index.php?route=" in SOME pages and not others!

Answer (score 0):

Products, Manufacturers, Information Pages and Categories all have SEO keyword fields, which you can find in their `DATA` tabs (except for Manufacturers which is in the `GENERAL` tab). These need to be set for all of the above to make them work. The reason the second link you've shown doesn't work is because it's `product/manufacturer/product` not just `product/manufacturer`

### EDIT

`product/manufacturer/product` is actually a manufacturer link - it's just poorly named by OpenCart. OpenCart still knows it is a manufacturer link and you can see that by the id that's passed along with it (`manufacturer_id` not `product_id`)

Also, OC isn't meant to rewrite it's standard URL's, only product, category, manufacturer (individual manufacturer pages not the list of manufacturers) and info pages. This works on all versions that I'm aware of so if it's not with yours, the vQmod is likely at fault and you'll need to get the developer of that to fix it

I've written a route editor mod myself that doesn't require going in and hacking up a vQmod to get it to work so I understand the complications with it

Comment: Believe it or not, I have already set Manufactuers SEO keyword in the General tab. It still doesn't explain why  breadcrumbs on a certain pages show "bishounenboutique.com/index.php?route=series" while some show "bishounenboutique.com/series " And "Psycho Pass" is a "series/ manufacturer", not a product. I am not sure why it shows that it's a product.

Comment: What would be your suggestion to rename "manufacturer" to "series", and since I have already done all of the above, adding in SEO keywords and all. Adding in the SEO keywords works well for information pages! Just the manufacturer/ series is giveing me a headache.. so, what do you suggest I should do to fix the breadcrumb inconsistencies...?